# Unable to play DRM/Protected content on Ungoogled-Chromium even after installing Widevine Plugin

Tags: windows, windows-11, chromium, drm

I am using Ungoogled-Chromium Version 120.0.6099.129 (Official Build, ungoogled-chromium) (64-bit) on Windows 11 Home v22H2 b22621.2715. I downloaded the installer from here - https://ungoogled-software.github.io/ungoogled-chromium-binaries/releases/windows/64bit/120.0.6099.129-1

It doesn't allow me to play DRM content like Netflix/AppleTV/Prime etc.

For e.g. Apple TV website gives the following message when I try to play a show/movie.

[image]

I did stuff as per the FAQ
https://chromium.woolyss.com/#widevine

1. My settings for protected content chrome://settings/content/protectedContent

[image]

2. I downloaded the zip file from https://dl.google.com/widevine-cdm/4.10.2710.0-win-x64.zip & unzipped it
3. I enabled developer mod in the browser settings & loaded the unzipped directory

I see this on chrome://extensions/

[image]

In errors, I see the following
[image]

What do I need to do to play DRM content?

Comment: “What do I need to do to play DRM content?” - Your not going to like the answer…use a supported browser

Comment: @Ramhound as per the FAQ, you are allowed to play it if you install the Widevine PLugin https://ungoogled-software.github.io/ungoogled-chromium-wiki/faq#windows

Comment: The example Chromium version in that FAQ is from more than 3 years ago. Based on the output you provided I don’t believe that FAQ is applicable in 2024. In fact the error specifies the reason it’s not working, the extension is manifest version 2, which has already been retired. You’ll have to wait until the extension is updated to support manifest version 3

Comment: @user93353: (1) It's [reported](https://github.com/ungoogled-software/ungoogled-chromium/issues/1831) that Drm works on ungoogled-chromium version 120. Are you on that version and did you get it from [here](https://ungoogled-software.github.io/ungoogled-chromium-binaries/)? (2) This [link](https://www.reddit.com/r/NixOS/comments/si6b42/ungoogledchromium_widevine_drm/) might be useful.

Comment: @harrymc I am on version 120. However after that post, Chromium changed their manifest structure - the manifest in that WideVine binary is still the older version

Comment: There are detailed instructions [Picking the Widevine Locks: Acquiring and Using an L3 CDM](https://www.ismailzai.com/blog/picking-the-widevine-locks), but it's too complex and long for me to try.

Comment: Widevine is created by Google, and ungoogled-chromium is breaking their business model. Moreover, a modified browser could easily rip DRM-streams. So I strongly suspect any solution posted here (or elsewhere) will be crawled straight into the top-priority inbox of a Widevine Engineer. In such scenario, any hack you can find at best will work for a couple of months (which seems to be confirmed by the links above).

Comment: Idea: Get these 2 files from another browser and transplant them into  Ungoogled-Chromium : `widevinecdm.dll` and `widevinecdm.dll.sig`. Look for other files or folders that have `widevinecdm` in their names.

Comment: If you only care about not running browsers that you don't want on your own system, you can play such videos in the browsers of a virtual machine or Windows Sandbox. *Fun fact: you can even record such videos by recording the virtual machine on the host.*

Answer (score 0):

If you need an open-source browser which is otherwise 100% google-free (if you change the default search-engine, that is) and [guaranteed to support Widevine](https://developers.google.com/widevine/drm/overview), take a look at [Firefox](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/).

It also has the advantage to have very good privacy options, and to be developed by a non-profit.

I'm not affiliated in any way with Mozilla, just a user.

Comment: I was using firefox for years. It's no longer that usable. Quite a few sites don't work well with it - it's no fault of Firefox - most developers now test only against Chrome. I moved to ungoogled-chromium because of this after years & years of using Firefox because of this